# Merged enums comparison -- Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, comparison

I understand how to merge two enums into one by doing the following.

```
enum Reptiles {
  Lizard = "Lizard",
  Snake = "Snake"
}

enum Mammals {
  Kangaroo = "Kangaroo",
  Dolphin = "Dolphin"
}

const Animals = { ...Mammals, ...Reptiles }
type Animals = typeof Animals
```

However, my issue comes when trying to perform comparisons on the code.

```
// This presents the following error 
// Error -- Type 'Mammals' is not assignable to type '{ Lizard: Reptiles.Lizard; Snake: Reptiles.Snake; Kangaroo: Mammals.Kangaroo; Dolphin: Mammals.Dolphin; }'.
const mySpiritAnimal: Animals = Animals.Kangaroo; 

// And this presents the following error 
// Error -- Argument of type '{ Lizard: Reptiles.Lizard; Snake: Reptiles.Snake; Kangaroo: Mammals.Kangaroo; Dolphin: Mammals.Dolphin; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Mammals'.
[Animals.Kangaroo].includes(mySpiritAnimal);
```

How do I merge enums and actually be able to use them effectively in comparisons etc?

**EDIT
If I then use the following code to type the enum properly, it still highlights a tsc error when changing the comparator in the array to `Lizard`.

```
type Animals = typeof Animals[keyof typeof Animals];


//ok
const mySpiritAnimal: Animals = Animals.Kangaroo;

//ok
[Animals.Kangaroo].includes(mySpiritAnimal);

// NOT ok -- Argument of type 'Mammals.Kangaroo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reptiles'.ts(2345)
[Animals.Lizard].includes(mySpiritAnimal);
```

Answer (score 1):

`type Animals = typeof Animals` is the type of the object that contains the enum members. You want the type of the enum values, which would be `type Animals = typeof Animals[keyof typeof Animals]`

```
const Animals = { ...Mammals, ...Reptiles }
type Animals = typeof Animals[keyof typeof Animals] // just Reptiles | Mammals


//ok
const mySpiritAnimal: Animals = Animals.Kangaroo; 

//ok
[Animals.Kangaroo].includes(mySpiritAnimal);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASsAOAXAlgG2AZygbwFBSgBlkAvAQwCcATKAXigCJjzqGAafKAZRDIGtgdRj37AGuAL65coSFACyZCBDKoseAgGkyIAOaUA9gaENtewwfacAIgdTwAFshAnb9pyHFTcAYwMgMRCgAQRBkFTUhbCgAOjjFZVUMNli4uCQ0TCgpRABPeEFQ8KShPIKDADMQsIiMAG0BXMqoMuBmotqAXWlcAHpegz5ff0CoCFyueGQKZEQO1QAuauLI+nm1GLN9CiMAbihpfsHcOvWMTZ1to06Y5x9UMCpMAApxyenZ9YBKXaA)

Comment: If i change it to "[Animals.Lizard].includes(mySpiritAnimal);" (with mySpriritAnimal still being Kangaroo) then I will get the following type error "Argument of type 'Mammals.Kangaroo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reptiles'."

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue by being more explicit with my enum in the following manner.

```
enum Reptiles {
  Lizard = "Lizard",
  Snake = "Snake"
}

enum Mammals {
  Kangaroo = "Kangaroo",
  Dolphin = "Dolphin"
}

enum Animals { 
  Kangaroo = Mammals.Kangaroo,
  Dolphin = Mammals.Dolphin,
  Lizard = Reptiles.Lizard,
  Snake = Reptiles.Snake
}

//ok
const mySpiritAnimal: Animals = Animals.Kangaroo;

//ok
[Animals.Kangaroo].includes(mySpiritAnimal);

//ok (yay!)
[Animals.Lizard].includes(mySpiritAnimal);
```